# Are outliers possible with categorical data

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Just want to make sure that I understand the meaning of an outlier.

> Question: Can you have an outlier of categorical data?

I think that to have an outlier you must first have some sort of measurement.  My reason is that any data point > 3*IQR (Interquartile range) is used to identifiy an outliner.

However, there is no measurement with categorical data, as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have 1000 people choose between apples and oranges. If 999 choose oranges and only one person chooses apple, I would say that that person is an outlier.

We use measurement as a way to detect anomalies. With categorical data you have to explain why choosing an apple is considered an anomaly (that data point does not behave as the rest 99.9% of the population).

There are also papers that talk about outliers in categorical data, for example http://www.cs.umn.edu/tech_reports_upload/tr2008/08-008.pdf.

Comment: Please could you provide an updated link? This one is dead.

Comment: @stefano Second the request for an updated link.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have another link for that paper that I found by using Google many years ago.

Comment: @Stefano can you include the title of paper here. It will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the standard treatment of this problem is, however I have a remark about the question. In order for the concept outlier to have any meaning you need to be able to define a distance between the values, that in this case may not be trivial i.e. is an apple closer to an orange or a pear?

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but just wanted to make sure that I understood it correctly and wasn't missing something.

Comment: Genetically and morphologically, an apple is closer to a pear than either is to an orange.

Answer (score 0):

After scanning the paper ["Understanding Categorical Similarity Measures for Outlier Detection"](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/215751/08-008.pdf) by Chandola, Boriah, and Kumar, it seems that the answer is yes, you can have outliers in categorical data.

From a *data point* perspective, we can have a data set with data points containing categorical values. One example of similarity is the number of values that are the same (called *overlap*) in two data points; more overlap then more similarity. There are techniques other than overlap, and which one is best depends on the problems, however some (such as *eskin*) have been observed to work well across a larger number of problems.

Another way to think about categorical outliers is if a categorical *value* within a collection of values from that categorical variable is an outlier. One way to interpret a categorical value outlier might be in frequency. Categorical values with that occur very infrequently might be thought of as outliers.  One way you might use this is simplify the problem by grouping infrequently occurring categories together.